# How to delete invisible space generated by transform: rotate?

Tags: html, css

I'm having some troubles with a invisible space generated in the bottom of my webpage when I apply rotation to the whole page and reverse this for some elements applying a negative rotation(-#deg). I used `overflow: hidden` combined with a `padding-bottom` to delete only the space desired but it looks like this generated a bug when you use the property `transform`in a hover effect. Here are some screenshot of the bug.

Before the bug:
http://prntscr.com/fjiuf4

Bug:
http://prntscr.com/fjiuqb

Any solution for one of this two problems? Another way to delete the space or to avoid the bug.

Here is a structure example of my page where you can see that a space is generated too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Your Website</title>
</head>
    
<style>

    #full{
        transform: rotate(-2deg);
        background-color: aqua;
        height: 1000px;
    }
    #content{
        transform: rotate(2deg);
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    #main{
        background-color: red;
        width: 80%;
    }
    footer{
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 80%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1000px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="full">
        <div id="content">
        <div id="main">
            <p>welkome</p>
        </div>

 <footer>
  <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
 </footer>
    
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly causes the bug? You mention "a hover effect", but there are no hover effects in the snippet.

Comment: There is no bug here, this looks exactly how it is suppose to based on your CSS. What space do you mean? ... Take of a screen shot of the above sample codes output and then make it look like the output you expect, so we'll see what you mean

Comment: Run the snippet and make it full screen, you will see a space at the bottom of the page. And that space is not supposing to be there.